# MariaDB REGEXP with escaping backslash has strange behaviour

Tags: regex, mariadb, escaping, backslash

I use MariaDB 10.6.8 and found this strange behaviour when using backslash and escaping backslash.

```
SET @x := 'abc\\def';
SELECT @x;
-- abc\def

SELECT @x REGEXP '\d'        ; -- 1  why this gives no error?
SELECT @x REGEXP '\\d'       ; -- 0  \d is not supported in MariaDB but what does this means
SELECT @x REGEXP '\\\d'      ; -- 0  ?
SELECT @x REGEXP '\\\\d'     ; -- 1  this makes sense: \\d, first slash escapes second
SELECT @x REGEXP '\\\\\d'    ; -- 1  ? 
SELECT @x REGEXP '\\\\\\\d'  ; -- 0  ok
SELECT @x REGEXP '\\\\\\\\d' ; -- 0  ok
```

Any idea what happens?

Comment: Because a single backslash is coded with 2 backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And why `'\d'` works too, and also 4 and 5 slash?

Comment: Why -1? There is no other SO question which address this problem. It is not only a simple escaping backslasch problem.

Comment: Run `select 'abc\\def';` from mysql command line. The result is "abc\def". That explains the results.

Comment: Not really. The only regexp which in my eyes makes sense is: `SELECT @x REGEXP '\\\\d'` which means `\\d` and search for string '\d'. But what means `REGEXP '\d'`? without escape?

Comment: `\d` matches a digit. Since your does not containt digits, there is no match. Note that double backslash is converted to single also in the expression. It makes more sense if you take the expressions and select those strings. Then you see the real regexp expession.

Comment: @slaakso MariaDB does support `\d`? I didn't know that and could not found that in the documentation. Nevertheless, the same pattern as above I  got with `SELECT'abcd\\ef' REGEXP '\e' `. What does `\e`?